# How can I protect my application's register API from spammers without using CAPTCHA?

Tags: security, mobile, captcha

My app has a register service that users can register themselves. However, someone with malicious intent can write a script to register thousands of accounts in seconds.

My back-end developer suggests we use captchas in our mobile apps. However I don't see any apps that are using captchas and they are bad UX.

My question is how to prevent this kind of attacks and secure our services in our app?

Comment: None of this has much to do with the client side, so I recommend that you switch your tags and your explanation to describe the server environment.

Comment: You can rate-limit by IP, and show captchas on suspicious behavior only.

Comment: There is no silver bullets for that kind of problems. Allow only a registration by IP, a captcha, or the need to have a real mail address are all the known solutions.

Comment: @JFPicard By "real mail address" do you mean like postal address? or a "real" e-mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not very ideal for StackOverflow but I remember that I ran into same problem once and hence I'm just sharing my implementations.

Yes the captcha is a bad bad user experience for a mobile application. This should be avoided. And yes, of course I avoided the captcha implementation too.

Dos attack can be prevented in so many ways and there are already some very established technology for that. You may track the hit from a specific IP address in your server side container and may block the IP address temporarily if you want. In case of distributed attacks, you may consider ignoring the requests which are beyond your capacity.

These are some trivial suggestions. You may consider having a firewall in your server side too which may give to these built in supports. CloudFlare is one of the firewalls used widely.

There are too many options you may take precaution on dos attacks. Just pick one of them in your server side. In case of your web application, you might consider keeping a google re-captcha, but for mobile application the idea of showing a captcha is horrible.

Answer (score 2):

At my current job, we're working on a passive mobile captcha SDK called [HumanDetect](https://developer.unify.id/products/humandetect/). It is transparent to your end users. It grabs sensor data to decide if the phone is being held by a human or not.

Answer (score 0):

1: You need to set up IP check and API call-ratio/ per second for calls made to your endpoint to limit calls from the same IP.

2: Easier method, log the IP that makes the call in the database and check against it, (will put heavy load on your DB since the calls go through your web server layer) and if calls get through, you probably don't have a secure server protecting you against DDOS anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps will be more useful for you to use some API methods to check registrations for spam.

As example, this API to check registrations for spam https://cleantalk.org/help/api-check-newuser

Answer (score -2):

You can add multiple layer of security over network. For this you should discuss with your backend developer about adding certificate pinning.

[This](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning) is a good explanation of how to do it.
You can also encrypt any sensitive information being passed over the network.

There are other methods like Basic, Digest authentication etc. which can be added to further enhance security.

Comment: That's not what he's asking about.